# Saving Rabbit mq messages into Azure storage using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika

Im using below code to receive rabbit mq messages.

```
import pika

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('user1', 'er41')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('10.*.*.**',
                                       5678,
                                       'test',
                                       credentials)



connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='testqueue', passive=true, durable=True)
channel.basic_consume(
    queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % gzip.decompress(body))

channel.basic_consume(queue='testqueue',
                      auto_ack=True,
                      on_message_callback=callback)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()


connection.close()
```

The message format is Json. I want to save the incoming messages into a file in specified path.
Could someone please let me know how to achieve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        file = open("out.log", "ab")
        file.write(body + b"\n")
        file.close()
```

This code save all mesaages into out.log file in current direcory.